# Can I use a keyboard/mouse with Mass Effect 3 on PS3?

Tags: ps3, mass-effect-3

I've got a bluetooth mouse/keyboard set I use on my PS3. I know some (very few) games support keyboard/mouse use, and it seems like [Mass Effect 2 did not support Keyboard/mouse](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/103/index/5536792/1) on PS3.

Can I use a mouse and keyboard to play Mass Effect 3 on PS3?

Answer (score 1):

I have no way of knowing for sure, as I have the PC version, but I am going to take an educated guess and say no. I say this because the PC version has no gamepad support, so if they didn't want to commit resources to gamepad support on PC I really doubt they commited resources to mouse and keyboard support on the PS3.